# Split Web page source string based on span id using componentsSeperatedByString not working objective c

Tags: html, objective-c, nsstring, macos-mojave

I have a requirement where i need to get the value of a span element from HTML web page source. I am able to get the entire HTML page source but i could not be able to retrieve the value inside the following span element

`<span id="MySpanID"> This is my span</span>`

I have used **componentsSeperatedByString** in order to split the HTML page source string into array elements based on span element as shown in the code line below.

`NSArray *arrayComponents = [htmlPageSourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<span id="MySpanID">"];`

The above line of code is always returning nil value due to which i could not able to split the string into array and retrieve the value present inside the span element . Can you please suggest any solution to retrieve the span element value from HTML Web page source?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're able to run this line of code

`NSArray *arrayComponents = [htmlPageSourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<span id="MySpanID">"];`

Because quotes inside `NSString` should be escaped with `\`.

Try to use

`NSArray *arrayComponents = [htmlPageSourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<span id=\"MySpanID\">"];`

It should work.